# Add objects to JSONObj

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I want to add objects inside to `JSONObj` when `onClick` and display in another `Activity` inside of a `ListView` as a `CardView`.

I tried something but nothing appears, no errors and I have no clue what's the problem.

**Here is my code for** **`JSONObj:`**

```
 private void writeJSON(String metodaPlata) throws JSONException {
    String numeVanzator = SharedPreference.getString(this, SharedPreference.USER_DATA, SharedPreference.NUME_VANZATOR, "");
    String jsonDataFromShared = SharedPreference.getString(this, SharedPreference.APP_DATA, SharedPreference.JSON_DATA, "");


    JSONObject jsonData;
    JSONArray dateJSON;
    JSONObject obj;
    JSONArray arrayForList;


    if (jsonDataFromShared.equals("")) {

        jsonData = new JSONObject();
        dateJSON = new JSONArray();
        obj = new JSONObject();
        arrayForList = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject objListaSiModalitate = new JSONObject();

        //       arrayForList.put(stock_list.toString());

        objListaSiModalitate.put("lista", new JSONArray(Util.getInstance().getVanzatorProduse()));
        objListaSiModalitate.put("metodaPlata", metodaPlata);

        obj.put("data", getDate(calendarData.getTimeInMillis()));
        obj.put("numeVanzator", numeVanzator);
        obj.put("numarClient", 0);
        obj.put("detaliiCos", objListaSiModalitate);

        dateJSON.put(obj);
        jsonData.put("jsonData", dateJSON.toString());

        SharedPreference.putString(this, SharedPreference.APP_DATA, SharedPreference.JSON_DATA, jsonData.toString());

    } else {

        jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonDataFromShared);
        dateJSON = jsonData.getJSONArray("jsonData");

        obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject objListaSiModalitate = new JSONObject();
        objListaSiModalitate.put("metodaPlata", metodaPlata);
        obj.put("produseSelectate", listaProdusePreview.getAdapter().getCount());
        int totalPrice = 0;
        for (VanzatorProduse v : Util.getInstance().getVanzatorProduse()) {
            int vPrice = Integer.parseInt(v.getPret());
            totalPrice = totalPrice + vPrice;
        }
        obj.put("sumaProduse", totalPrice);
        obj.put("data", getDate(calendarData.getTimeInMillis()));
        obj.put("numeVanzator", numeVanzator);
        obj.put("numarClient", numarVanzare);
        obj.put("detaliiCos", objListaSiModalitate);

        dateJSON.put(obj);

        jsonData.put("jsonData", dateJSON);

        System.out.println("jsonData" + dateJSON);
        SharedPreference.putString(this, SharedPreference.APP_DATA, SharedPreference.JSON_DATA, jsonData.toString());

    }
}
```

**My `JSONManager` :**

```
 //Create list of Cards because we need to show list for date selected
public List<Card> readJSON(String dateFromCalendar) throws JSONException {

    String JSON = SharedPreference.getString(Util.get(), SharedPreference.APP_DATA, SharedPreference.JSON_DATA, "");
    String numeVanzator = SharedPreference.getString(Util.get(), SharedPreference.USER_DATA, SharedPreference.NUME_VANZATOR,"");

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JSON);

    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("jsonData");
    List<Card> listCard = null;
    Card card = null;

    listCard = new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i =0; i< contacts.length();i++) {

        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
        String data = c.getString("data");

        if (data.equals(dateFromCalendar)){
            String numeVanzato = c.getString("numeVanzator");
            if (numeVanzato.equals(numeVanzator)){

                String numarClient = c.getString("numarClient");
                String sumaProduse = c.getString("sumaProduse");
                String produseselectate = c.getString("produseSelectate");

                card = new Card(numarClient, produseselectate, sumaProduse);
                listCard.add(card);
            }
        }
    }
    return listCard;
}}
```

**Card Object :**

```
public class Card {
public String numarCumparator;
public String listaProduse;
public String sumaProduse;

public Card(String numarCumparator, String listaProduse, String sumaProduse) {
    this.numarCumparator = numarCumparator;
    this.listaProduse = listaProduse;
    this.sumaProduse = sumaProduse;
}

public Card() {
}

public String getNumarCumparator() {
    return numarCumparator;
}

public void setNumarCumparator(String numarCumparator) {
    this.numarCumparator = numarCumparator;
}

public String getListaProduse() {
    return listaProduse;
}

public void setListaProduse(String listaProduse) {
    this.listaProduse = listaProduse;
}

public String getSumaProduse() {
    return sumaProduse;
}

public void setSumaProduse(String sumaProduse) {
    this.sumaProduse = sumaProduse;
}
}
```

**Card Adapter :**

```
public class CardArrayAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
private static final String TAG = "CardArrayAdapter";
private List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();

static class CardViewHolder {
    TextView line1;
    TextView line2;
    TextView line3;
}

public CardArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

@Override
public void add(Card object) {
    cardList.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.cardList.size();
}

@Override
public Card getItem(int index) {
    return this.cardList.get(index);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    CardViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_card, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new CardViewHolder();
        viewHolder.line1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNumarCumparator);
        viewHolder.line2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listaProduse);
        viewHolder.line3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sumaProduse);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (CardViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    Card card = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.line1.setText(card.getNumarCumparator());
        viewHolder.line2.setText(card.getListaProduse());
        viewHolder.line3.setText(card.getSumaProduse());

    return row;
}

public Bitmap decodeToBitmap(byte[] decodedByte) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}

}
```

**Layout for Card:**

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewNumarCumparator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="NumarCumparator" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listaProduse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewNumarCumparator"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="NumarProduse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sumaProduse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="SumaProdsue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Layout for `ListView`:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/gray_color">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewVanzatorActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnAdaugaProduse"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewDataCurenta"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope you understand my question..

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to send data from Activity to another is to pass parcelable data in the Intent bundle.

- Make card implement Parcelable
- Pass the items to the intent

  ```
  public void startSecondActivity(List<Card> cards) {
      Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
      i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("EXTRA_CARDS", new ArrayList<Card>(cards));
      startActivity(i);
  }
  ```
- Retrieve it like this in the second activity

  ```
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  List<Card> cards = (ArrayList<Card>)bundle.getParcelableArrayList("EXTRA_CARDS");
  ```